# Date values from MS SQL query into Google Charts (Razor)

Tags: javascript, sql-server, razor, google-visualization

Hopefully a simple question that someone can answer. I'm trying to create a google charts graph that takes the 2-column results of a SQL server query and plots them on an X-Y axis.

The first column (the x values on my graph) are dates that are in the following format: `4/5/2014 12:00:00 AM` and the second column (the y values) are a standard float.  I convert these results into a json-formatted string required for google charts with the following asp.net parser:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
         {
         conn.Open();
         using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select game_date, fb_avg_velo, cb_avg_velo, ch_avg_velo, sl_avg_velo, oth_avg_velo from pitching_speed where player_code = 'bjones' order by game_date asc", conn))
                {
                    adapter.Fill(dt);

                    List<string> rowsList = new List<string>();
                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        rowsList.Add("[" + row["game_date"] + ", " + row["fb_avg_velo"] + "]");
                    }
                    rows = String.Join(", ", rowsList);
                }
     }
```

I then use the following javascript function to populate a datatable to create my graph:

```
 function drawChart() {
    var data1 = new google.visualization.DataTable()
    data1.addColumn('date', 'Date');
    data1.addColumn('number', 'Velocity');
    data1.addRows([@Html.Raw(rows)]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data1, {
        title: 'Fast Ball Speed by Date',
    });
```

The issue is I don't think google charts recognizes my date format so the graph doesn't render. I know there is a Date() function in javascript but I don't know how to implement it in this case.

Answer (score 0):

See [The “right” JSON date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286204/the-right-json-date-format) for how to format the date. Try `row["game_date"].ToString("O")` in the C#.